# AJAX not sending data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to get data from an input field and send it to PHP by POST but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#id_1").change(function () {
          var rat1 = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              type: "post",
              data: rat1,
              success: function (response) {
                  // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)

              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
              }


          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

this is the input form

```html
<input type="number" name="your_awesome_parameter" id="id_1" class="rating" data-clearable="remove"
                           data-icon-lib="fa" data-active-icon="fa-heart" data-inactive-icon="fa-heart-o"
                           data-clearable-icon="fa-trash-o"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a name for the parameter. It should be:

```
data: { param_name: rat1 }
```

Then in `upload.php` you access it with `$_POST['param_name']`

Comment: tried this but still nothing. Post is empty on the upload.php page :(

Comment: How are you determining that post is empty?

Comment: $x = $_POST['param_name'];
echo $x;

$_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['param_name'];
var_dump($_POST['param_name']);
var_dump($_SESSION['var']);

var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @AAZ where are you checking the response ? because success callback you have done nothing

Comment: @SusheelSingh I am not sure how I can do that. I am new to Ajax and my basics are weak

Comment: Added the parameter and also thanks @SusheelSingh as adding the response worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, did you imported Jquery into your project?
I tested your code and I with the minor change that Barmar specified and it is working for me.

Try to use this code in your php file and see if you get any response in the developer tools console.

```
$data = $_POST["param_name"];
echo json_encode([$data]);
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that your used? Also I am not sure what to put in the response and how it works so maybe thats why it is creating the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way men

```
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1, valorCaja2){
    var parametros = {
            "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
            "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   'ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php',
            type:  'post',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    $("#resultado").html(response);
            }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`change` on input type `number` is not working in older versions of browsers, I think not sure. But try this below solution as you are using input type `number`.

```
$("#id_1").on("mouseup keyup",function () {
    //your logic here
});
```

and passing data as already mentioned by others:

```
data: { param_name: rat1 }
```